Use multithreading on scrapy scraper using selenium
I'm working on a scrapy scraper which is using selenium to scrape data but this process is time taking.
It can only scrape 2000 records in 12 hours. I want to speed up the scraper using multithreading.
But when I use multithreading or ThreadPoolExecutor, the program start ignoring some functions or may be the process is too fast to do other work.
How can I use multithreading in scrapy spider with selenium?
Here's my code:
   def parse(self, response):
            existing_vins = self.read_existing_vins('ucars.csv')
            unique_lots_vins = set(existing_vins)
        
            while True:
                lot_urls = self.get_page_data()
                for lot_url in lot_urls:
                    vin_from_url = lot_url.split('-')[-1]
                    vin_from_url = vin_from_url.upper()
                    if vin_from_url in unique_lots_vins:
                        continue

                    self.driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
                    self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
                    lot_details = self.scrape_lot_details(self.driver, lot_url)
                    lot_number = lot_details['lot_number']
                    vin = lot_details['vin']
                    if vin not in unique_lots_vins:
                        unique_lots_vins.add(vin)
                        self.save_to_csv(lot_details)
                    self.driver.close()
                    self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])
                    time.sleep(2)

                if not self.go_to_next_page():
                    break

                time.sleep(5)

This is the simple code before implementing multithread and here's the after:
def parse(self, response):
            existing_vins = self.read_existing_vins('ucars.csv')
            unique_lots_vins = set(existing_vins)
        
            while True:
                lot_urls = self.get_page_data()
                threads = []

                with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:  # Adjust max_workers as needed
                    for lot_url in lot_urls:
                        vin_from_url = lot_url.split('-')[-1].upper()
                        if vin_from_url in unique_lots_vins:
                            continue
                        thread = executor.submit(self.process_lot_details, lot_url, unique_lots_vins)
                        threads.append(thread)

                    for thread in as_completed(threads):
                        thread.result()

                if not self.go_to_next_page():
                    break

                time.sleep(5)

When this ThreadPoolExecutor run, it goes to process_lot_details and after scraping data from the site, it should save in the csv file. Here's the code:
def process_lot_details(self, lot_url, unique_lots_vins):
            try:
                lot_details = self.scrape_lot_details(self.driver, lot_url)  
                lot_number = lot_details['lot_number']
                vin = lot_details['vin']
                if vin not in unique_lots_vins:
                    unique_lots_vins.add(vin)
                    self.save_to_csv(lot_details)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing lot details for URL {lot_url}: {e}")

    def save_to_csv(self, lot_details, filename='ucars.csv'):
            file_exists = os.path.isfile(filename)
            self.initialize_csv(filename, lot_details.keys())
            with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as output_file:
                dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=lot_details.keys())
                if not file_exists:
                    dict_writer.writeheader()
                dict_writer.writerow(lot_details)

        def initialize_csv(self, filename, fieldnames):
            if not os.path.isfile(filename):
                with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
                    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                    dict_writer.writeheader()

It doesn't save data to csv file. Also there's another issue, If I use ThreadPool, It doesn't open multiple tabs, it just work in 1 tab and that's almost same as without using ThreadPool.
It extract URLs from one page and then go to those URLs one by one for scraping data from that page. But this is time taking that's why I want to use multithreading.
It should work with ThreadPoolExecutor and open multiple tabs to scrape data concurrently and save extracted data to csv file.
Here's the complete code on GitHub repository
https://github.com/Rehman00786/python/blob/main/ucars_spider.py

You are using exactly zero Scrapy features (plus one parsel call) so consider removing Scrapy from the code, it should be more straightforward without it.
